# No option to set bounties

Tags: support, bounties

I'm scrolling to the point — just below the comments — where bounties used to be on multiple Stack Exchange sites, but I no longer have the option to set them. Why is that?

I am still seeing the 'question eligible for bounty in X days' message on some Stack Exchange sites (such as Stack Exchange Meta), just nothing for questions which are already over the threshold. Stack Overflow doesn't appear to show either the eligible or the bounty setting message at present. Same with Server Fault, etc.

On such question is https://serverfault.com/questions/774381/configuring-ipv6-via-ipv4-using-openvpn

Comment: What site? What question?

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked

When viewing your own question, you will see "this question is eligible for bounty" with a countdown until those two days pass. However, when viewing question posted by a different user, you won't see such a message, there will simply be no link whatsoever if the question is not eligible for bounty from you. (There can be other reasons, e.g. not enough reputation, 3 active bounties, etc.)

I have started a related feature request few years ago, [Let me know why I can't start a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151395/let-me-know-why-i-cant-start-a-bounty), which if implemented, will prevent such confusion.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. I'm not seeing the bounty setting message or the 2 day warning on certain sites. I don't understand how this is an answer. I'm confused. Are you seeing the same question as me?

Comment: Sorry, can't explain any better. You don't see it because it's not your questions.

Comment: You must be seeing a different question than me. This is really destabilizing.

Comment: No I'm not. I also don't see anything to start a bounty or any message for 2 days warning [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/774381/configuring-ipv6-via-ipv4-using-openvpn) because it was posted only 3 hours ago, and I'm not its author

Comment: Ok with the new edit I think I understand. Ok. That was really weird.

Comment: Agree it's a bad UX, that's why I started that feature request. :)