# Cannot add bounty to question

Tags: support, bounties

I have at least 75 rep. I don't see any link underneath the comments to start a bounty:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have posted an answer to that question. That makes the minimum bounty you can set 100 reputation, not 50. This is to avoid people posting bounties to draw attention to their answers, rather than the question. From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> - To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @FrankerZ yes in the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) answer: "Note: If you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50)"

Comment: Seems a little silly. People can just draw attention, and then post.

Comment: True, but that only works for old questions (bounties can only be offered after 2 days).

Comment: Yeah, this was for an older style question. I swear I was going insane for a bit: Literally clicked start a bounty, added the answer, went back to start the bounty and the button was just gone.

Comment: @FrankerZ I  agree about the confusion, feel free to support [my feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151395/let-me-know-why-i-cant-start-a-bounty) which will reduce the confusion. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol, literally was just in the process of creating one